# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions with fast switching

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbar in which it has tabs, each tab is a fragment. Everything is great except when I do fast switching between the tabs. When I do fast switching, I get this bug:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Here is my code for OnTapSelected

```
if (mFragment == null) {

    mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);


} else {


    ft.attach(mFragment);
}
```

Any way I can fix this? Or if not , how can I at least catch this exception (like where to put the try/catch) so my app does not get crashed?

thank you

Comment: where are you committing the fragmenttransaction?

Comment: I am not. When I add a tab listener, I am commiting only in the constructor. But onTabSelected, i dont commit after adding/attaching.should I ?

Comment: if you don't commit, none of the changes actually get applied. i don't think it gets committed automatically. here are the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())

Comment: I am able to switch though succesfully .If changes dont get applied, I wouldnt have been able to have successfull switching

Comment: without more code, I can't say for sure. i'm doing something similar in one of my apps but i never got that error

Comment: I tried putting committing and it started crashing saying commit is already called. So I guess it is called automatically. Hmm, I am not sure what more code I need to put as this is my OnTabSelected. In the OnTabUnselected, I just detach the fragment. Is there a way  I can catch this exception, so I dont crash?

Comment: i don't think so. the exception is thrown in FragmentManager.execPendingActions if there are already actions executing. at least that is what it looks like from the source code. so it looks like if you are already commit a change and you try to change again, it is already exectuing and it throws an exception.

Comment: Is there a way to see if it is aready executing? At least I can ignore this extra action that is messing the whole thing up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18327/discussion-between-toadzky-and-snake)

Comment: getChildFragmentManger()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using attach, try using show/hide. you will need references to all of your fragments, but if you add them all, then show the right one and hide the rest that might fix it.

Comment: Indeed , it did fix it. Thank you so muuch

Comment: Be warned though: This will need a *lot* more memory as all fragments need to be on the heap all the time; OutOfMemory Exceptions might happen.

(I know that is very old but people are still following this tip).